# UILabel sizeThatFits returns different values for different devices. Why?

Tags: swift

In my swift project I need to resize a UILabel to fit a text. I use sizeThatFits to calculate the size. However the results vary enormously among the devices. The width is limited to 280 points. For iPhone 5/s the height is calculated to 19 but for iPhone 4s it is 115. iPhone 6+ determines it should be a lot more.

This is the entire code snippet. For testing I have used fixed width rather than the calculated values. The label is set to be the full size of its superview in storyboard. That is why I change the bottom constraint to do the resizing. Any idea why the different devices get different values even when width is set to the same value?

```
 var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

 let attrStr = self.infoLabel.attributedText
 var width = bounds.width - 40

 let size = self.infoLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(bounds.width - 40, bounds.height))
 let delta = (self.infoLabel.frame.size.height) - size.height
 bottomConstaint.constant += delta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used self.view.bounds rather than UIDevice.mainScreen().bounds, and moved it from viewWillAppear to viewDidLayoutSubviews, and got a perfect result for all devices.